# Order by, put 0's at the end whilst maintaining the ascending search order

Tags: mysql

I have a query that uses `ORDER BY ASC` and as such 0's come up first. I would like them to come up last whilst still maintaining the ascending search order. How can I achieve this?

An example of this is:

```
SELECT product_price ORDER BY product_price ASC
```

So instead of

```
0
1
2
3
```

I would want

```
1
2
3
0
```

Comment: Your question is better now after your clarification, it wont waste others time now. Always provide necessary details and context, expected output to get ACCURATE answers :)

Comment: After I posted it I re-read it and realised there may be confusion hence the update :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have MySQL to test against, but this works in SQL Server and Advantage Database Server:

```
SELECT 
  product_price 
ORDER BY 
  CASE product_price WHEN 0 then 99999999 ELSE product_price END
```

Replace the `99999999` series with the maximum value of the `product_price` column type.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT product_price FROM tablename ORDER BY IF(product_price=0,4294967295,product_price) ASC
```

Comment: I think you miss the 'from table'

Comment: I winder what it would do to the performance. This requires a full table scan. It may be better to split the query into two parts and Union them, I wonder.

Comment: This throws up an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(hire_car_addday=0,4294967295,hire_car_addday) ASC' `

Comment: @Chris I just copy/pasted your SQL, which had no `FROM` subcluase - fixed it.

Comment: @srini.venigalla The query itself is a full table scan, so no harm done.

Comment: Dont worry I added the `FROM`, it errors on the `IF` in `ORDER BY IF`

Comment: @Chris Not here .. `select version()` gives `5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1` ... what's your data type?

Comment: If it is a 32bit system try 2147483647 instead of 4294967295 or whatever is appropriate for your business logic.

Comment: I tried with just `4000` and it didnt work either. Ken's solution worked so im sorted now thankyou. +1 for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

For the  best performance, use a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_price > 0
    ORDER BY
        product_price ASC
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
       product_price = 0
)
```

The alternative, uses filesort which can be really slow when you have large tables.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
ORDER BY
    IF(product_price = 0, 1, 0) ASC
    ,product_price ASC
```

yeilds `Using filesort`. This means a temporary table is being written on disk. Very slow when you're dealing with large queries.